# Split a multi-dimensional SI unit into its individual units and list them

Tags: arrays, r, regex, string

I'd like to use regex to pick out units in a multi-dimensional unit, output it as a list of SI unit characters.

For example, split a unit of 3 dimensions: `kg/h/ml` or `kg h-1ml-1` to this `'kg'` `'h'` `'ml'`.

So the separator is always either a space before or after, a `-1` after, or a `/` before the unit. Sometimes I get a `.` as well, and that's before a unit.

This means that the characters actually don't matter... as long as the separators are identified.

I've provided an example list of n-dimensional "units" (in this case, 3):

```
eggie <- c('kg/h/ml', 'mg h-1kPa-1', 'kg h-1 l-1', 
           'kg /h /ml', 'kg / h / ml', '% /h.ml')
```

The output should provide a matrix with n columns (in this case, 3), otherwise output an error for cases like `kgh-1l-1` which does not have a delimiter between the first and second unit.

**Update**. To provide more information on the "error" since I've been asked about it -- if *n* is 3 but the output spits out 2(or less) units for any of the strings in the list, it should not output a matrix in this case. I could probably code that part of the function, but if anyone can make the error message call out the position of the error(s) that would be awesome (since that would take old me a while to figure out, but anyone else, seconds).

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] "kg"  "h"   "ml"
[2,] "mg"  "h"   "kPa"
[3,] "kg"  "h"   "l"
[4,] "kg"  "h"   "ml"
[5,] 'kg"  "h"   "ml"
[6,] "%"   "h"   "ml"
```

I have gone through the tutorial in [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html) and figure that it may require a function containing a combination of `gsub` and `strsplit` (I could be wrong altogether). But it's like learning a whole new language for me.

Any help (or a point to the right resource to figure this out) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could u show the full expected output

Comment: Here is a `base R` approach `read.table(text=gsub("[^%[:alpha:]]", " ", eggie), header= FALSE)`

Comment: You have not specified what it should look like if `kgh-1l-1` is in the input. Do you mean you do not need the matrix at all then?

Comment: Hmm I think I did, I said output an error but I guess I wasn't clear on that. I will update the relevant section in a bit.

Comment: Then doesn't akrun's suggestion work for you? Or do you want to specifically match just the `-1`, `.`, `/` or whitespace as delimiters (with [`"(?:-1|[/.[:space:]])+"`](https://ideone.com/10bB4Q))?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, looks like akrun's method works. Your approach also seems to work.

Comment: The difference is that I specify the delimiters exactly as you specified. Akrun's approach is more generic, `[^%[:alpha:]]` replaces each single char that is not `%` and a letter (I suggested a similar expression with `strsplit` and `gsub` at first, but deleted my comment.). The `(?:-1|[/.[:space:]])+` is whitelisting the separators (matches 1 or more chunks of `-`+digits or whitespace/`/`/`.`. Which approach is best for you? Will there be more non-alpha chars (or maybe char sequences?) you'd like to keep/remove?

Comment: That's a good point. Specifying the delimiters would be the better solution for me, in this case. Thanks for being patient and clarifying what I didn't understand at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to split the data you have with the exact delimiter patterns, that are

- `-`+digit(s)
- one of the chars: `/`, `.` or whitespace

The pattern for this is

```
pat <- "(?:-1|[/.[:space:]])+"
```

The `(?:-1|[/.[:space:]])+` regex pattern matches 1 or more sequences of `-1` char sequence (`-1`) or (`|`) any char that is `/`, `.` or whitespace (`[/.[:space:]]`).

Use

```
read.table(text=gsub(pat, " ", eggie), header=FALSE, col.names=c("Unit1","Unit2","Unit3"))
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/G6Z0Rl)

Once the number of fields is not as expected, the error is produced (see `stderr`):

> Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
>    line 7 did not have 3 elements
>   Calls: read.table -> scan
>   Execution halted